# How to run a command-line typescript file in the vite.js environment?

Tags: node.js, vite

I have a front-end project using vite (with the svelte-kit template) and I would like to run some command-line scripts in typescript using the very same environment (using node 20.5). For example, I would like to have typescript support, be able to import static assets like a text-file

```
import assetAsString from './shader.glsl?raw'
```

or environment variables like

```
import.meta.env.PROD
```

and share some functions with my back-end code running on the server or this. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: If you only want to strip TypeScript, you can run `esbuild` on the commandline and pipe it to Node.js. But that will not do vite-specific things like `?raw` import and `import.meta.env`. Only way I can think of to do that is to configure a new entry point in your `vite.build.rollupOptions` config, then actually do a `vite build`, then run node on the output. :-(